# AutoCompleteTextView на Android

Tags: java, android

Доброго всем дня, помогите с одним вопросом. Есть у меня AutoCompleteTextView и там содержаться данные, заключенные в кавычки, т.е. например: Л.Н. Толстой "Война и Мир". Если в поиск вводить Мир или просто, "и", то результаты есть, а если написать Война, то ничего нет. То есть нужно обязательно указать первую кавычку и в запрос ввести "Война, тогда донаборщик выдаст нужную строку. ТАк вот как сделать так, чтобы не нужно было вводить кавычки? Писать фильтр?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась написанием фильтра, в котором отправляется запрос на сервер и возвращается ArrayList. Полезная ссылка http://habrahabr.ru/post/243853/

Comment: Не могли бы вы существенный для решения код добавить прямо в ответ? Так он будет полезен другим участникам, которые ищут решения для похожих задач.