# AutoCompleteTextView на Android проблема с поиском слов с кавычками

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

Есть у меня AutoCompleteTextView и там содержатся некоторые данные, заключенные в кавычки, например: ООО "Строймонтаж консалт" и т.д.

- при вводе в поиске **ооо** выдает: **ООО "Строймонтаж консалт"**
- при вводе в поиске **конс** выдает: **ООО "Строймонтаж консалт"**
- при вводе в поиске **Строй** ничего не выдает
- при вводе в поиске **монтаж** ничего не выдает
- при вводе в поиске **салт** ничего не выдает

Помогите, пожалуйста, настроить AutoCompleteTextView.

**Обновление**

[AutoCompleteTextView на Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438411/autocompletetextview-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android) – я видел, но решение, использованное в нем, не подходит для моих нужд. Печально если придется писать свой обработчик. Если есть предположения о причинах такой работы AutoCompleteTextView , поделитесь со мной, буду признателен.

Comment: Посмотрите тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438411/autocompletetextview-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android

Comment: вам, возможно, придется самому делать поиск

Comment: Этот пост я смотрел, но решение, использованное в нем, не подходит для моих нужд. Печально если придется писать свой обработчик. Если есть предположения о причинах такой работы AutoCompleteTextView , поделитесь со мной, буду признателен. Спасибо.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.